# What is the most electrically conductive material at standard temperature and pressure?

Tags: conductors

Searching the internet, I find plenty of sources telling you the most conductive *element* is silver, and plenty of articles about potential room temperature superconducting alloys (none of which have been proven yet at time of writing). But I have not been able to find a source that says whether there are any alloys or other materials that are more conductive than silver (but obviously not superconducting).

Comment: [Silver or graphene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69689/are-there-compounds-more-conductive-than-silver-ag), but graphene reduces electron mobility as a side-effect.